# Duda con query en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Voy a intentar explicar mi duda de manera sencilla ya que es algo compleja.

Tengo una tabla llamada `formacion` con los campos `ID`,`Tipo`,`Categoría` y `SubCategoria`

Una tabla llamada `alumnos` con los campos `NIA` y `apellidos_nombre`.

Una tabla llamada `alumnos_formacion` con los campos `NIA` e `idFormacion`. Aqui guardo el nia del alumno y sus id de formaciones que tiene. `NIA` clave foránea al `NIA` de la tabla `alumnos` e `idFormacion` clave foranea a `idFormacion` de la tabla `formacion`

Ejemplo:

```
NIA:1234  IdFormacion:1 

NIA:1234  IdFormacion:3 

NIA:1234  IdFormacion:4
```

Por ultimo tengo una tabla llamada `Ofertas` con una series de campos entre lo que me interesan son:

`requisito1`,`requisito2`,`requisito3`,`requisito4`,`requisito5`,`requisito6`,
`requisito7`,`requisito8`

Estos campos contiene claves foráneas a los id de la tabla `formacion`

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es una consulta `SQL` que me traiga el nombre de los alumnos cuyas formaciones coincidan con al menos un requisito de la oferta, el que mas requisitos cumpla aparecerá en primer lugar.

Pongo un ejemplo:

`Alumno 1` con `NIA: 1234` tiene las formaciones: `id1`,`id2`,`id3`

`Alumno 2` con `NIA: 4321` tiene las formaciones: `id3`,`id4`,`id5`

La oferta pide las formaciones: `id1`,`id4`,`id5`

En este caso el nombre del `Alumno2` debería aparecer en primer lugar y el `Alumno1` en segundo lugar.

He realizado esta consulta `SQL` pero creo que no tiene nada que ver:

```
SELECT DISTINCT apellidos_nombre FROM alumnos 
    INNER JOIN alumnos_formacion
        ON alumnos.nia = alumnos_formacion.nia 
    INNER JOIN ofertas
        ON alumnos_formacion.idFormacion = ofertas.requisito1 OR ofertas.requisito2 OR ofertas.requisito3 OR ofertas.requisito4 OR ofertas.requisito5 OR ofertas.requisito6 OR ofertas.requisito7 OR ofertas.requisito8
WHERE idOferta = 1
```

Comment: Más o menos se iba entendiendo lo que planteabas, pero aquí me perdí: *La oferta pide las formaciones: id1,id4,id5*  ¿qué significa eso?  Creo que sería bueno que pongas un ejemplo sencillo de los resultados esperados.

Comment: En mi tabla ofertas guardo una series de valores entre ellos se encuentra el campo requisito 1, requisito 2, etc que guardo valores que son claves foránea a la tabla formación. El requisito 1 es clave foránea al ID 1 de la tabla formaciones

Comment: Eso lo entiendo. Lo que no entendí es eso de que la oferta **pide** las formaciones ... Creo que si [editas la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/172149/edit) y pones la estructura de cada tabla y un pequeño ejemplo de los resultados esperados ayudaría a entender el problema. Tampoco se entiende en algunos casos a través de qué columnas se relaciona cada tabla.